# How do I check if all the characters of a string are present in another string?

Tags: javascript, string

It's about a basic algorithm challenge, in which the user has to return `true` if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array, *e.g.*:

1. `["hello", "Hello"]` should return `true`.
2. `["Alien", "line"]` should return `true`.

So far, I've tried this:

```
function mutation(arr) {
    var value1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
    var value2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < value2.length; i++) {
        if (value1.indexOf(value2.charAt(i)) !== -1)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

While passing the value `mutation(["hello", "hey"])`, it isn't returning `false`.

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049306/how-to-check-two-string-have-same-characters-including-special-characters/37049804#37049804)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

Comment: I'd say exact duplicate of the answer @maioman pointed out; the one Mike pointed out answers finding a single substring within another string, but not matching for every individual character in a string within another string.

Comment: Neither of those are a duplicate. maioman's requires that all the characters are the same, or if not, that the missing chars of the second string. Mike's is looking for a substring. Neither are the same as this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like youre pretty close, except you seem to be returning true early. Instead, if the `indexOf` returns `-1` break from the loop and return false, otherwise let the loop run to completion and return true afterward (since it didnt return early, we know all chars are present)

```
function mutation(arr) {
   var value1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
   var value2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  for(var i=0;i<value2.length;i++){
    if(value1.indexOf(value2.charAt(i)) === -1) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var value1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var value2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var result = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < value2.length; i++) {
    if (value1.indexOf(value2.charAt(i)) === -1)
      result = false;
  }
  alert(result);
}
mutation(["Alien", "line"]);
mutation(["hello", "Hello"]);
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/csauovjhFeFltkbqRxjx?p=preview