# How to implement Java's HashMap.equals(HashMap) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hashmap, keyvaluepair

I am trying to write a function that takes two strings and returns whether or not they have the same frequency of letters. It is assumed that neither string is null.

Here is my Java implementation:

```
  public void addToMap(HashMap<String, Integer> map, String s){
  if(map.get(s) == null){
    map.put(s, 1);
  } else{
    map.put(s, map.get(s)+1);
  }
}

  public boolean perm(String a, String b){
    if(a.length() != b.length()){
      return false;
    }
    HashMap<String, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> bMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
      addToMap(aMap, a.substring(i,i+1));
      addToMap(bMap, b.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    return aMap.equals(bMap);
  }
```

I am trying to replicate this in JavaScript:

```
const addToMap = (map, s) => {
  if(map[s] == null){
    map[s] = 1;
  } else{
    map[s] = map[s]+1;
  }
}

const perm = (a,b) => {
  if(a.length != b.length){
    return false;
  }
  let aMap = new Map();
  let bMap = new Map();
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    addToMap(aMap, a.substring(i,i+1));
    addToMap(bMap, b.substring(i,i+1));
  }
  return aMap === bMap;
}
```

I tested perm("abca", "bcaa") for both implementations. The Java code returns true, which is correct. However, the JS functions return false.

Is there a way to return that two maps are equal in JS when they have the same keys and values, but in a different order?

Comment: If your code works, consider asking this in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The problem is the way you compere both `Map()` objects in Javascript. I strongly suggest you to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948335/how-can-i-check-if-two-map-objects-are-equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I created that works:

```
const addToMap = (map, s) => {
  if(map.has(s)){
    map.set(s, map.get(s)+1);
  } else{ map.set(s, 1);}
}

const perm = (a, b) => {
  if(a.length != b.length){ return false; }
  let aMap = new Map();
  let bMap = new Map();
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    addToMap(aMap, a.substring(i, i+1));
    addToMap(bMap, b.substring(i, i+1));
  }
  return aMap.toString() == bMap.toString();
}
const s1 = "abcda";
const s2 = "cdbaa";
console.log(perm(s1, s1));
```

What happened is I was using the wrong syntax for Map(). I was using bracket notation to create my key value pairs instead or Map.prototype methods.

See this code sample:

```
let m = new Map();
m.set(1, "a");
m[2] = "b";
console.log(m);
//Output: Map { 1 => 'a', 2: 'b' }
```

Using the Map.get and Map.set methods works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is how you compare two map objects. In Java you use equels but if you use == you will get same always false result.
In js you could compare two object by loop through keys and compare each key existance and value or for shorter but with little overhead just do JSON.stringify(aMap)===JSON.stringify(bMap) instead of aMap==bMap

**Update**
As you mention JSON.stringify not work. (Usually when you loop through keys they will go in alphabetical order, but that is browser dependent feature as object in js is usually not ordered key-value properties).

So when I mention you just need to compare two maps. For example:

```
const isSubMap = function(mapA, mapB) {
  for (let key in mapA) {
    if (!mapB[key] || mapA[key] !== mapB[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

But as for me I would go with different approach of solving this problem:
1) Sum charcodes for all chars from string A and string B and then compare sumA == sumB;
2) Just create a map of differences. So chars from string A would add key to the map with value 1 and or increment counter, and the chars from string B would decrements counter if property value bigger than 1 or create new one with -1 value (if value === 0 then remove key property from the object). In the end check if object has zero properties with Object.keys(obj).length === 0;

Comment: It returns false, still. This fails:
console.log(perm("abca", "bcaa"));
The strings compared:
Map { a: 2, b: 1, c: 1 }
Map { b: 1, c: 1, a: 2 }
I don't see why these would pass.

Comment: That does work, however, adding this to my code would force me to traverse the whole string and the map, which I'd rather not do.
I found a solution to the permutation question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948335/how-can-i-check-if-two-map-objects-are-equal

The Map object in JS just doesn't compare.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/37049306/7066218

But for my JS map issue, it seems that